# Typedef for nested templated class

Tags: c++, templates

In .hpp file I have

```
template <SomeEnum E>
class SomeClass {
   //many definitions
   class InnerClass {
       //Some stuff
   };
   typedef std::map<std::string, InnerClass> InnerMapType;
};
```

in .cpp files I have

```
template <SomeEnum E>
SomeClass<E>::~SomeClass() {
   InnerMapType::iterator iter;
   //Iterate over resources
}
```

Compiler gives syntax error in `InnerMap::iterator iter;` claiming semicolon is expected before iter. If I remove the `template <SomeEnum E>` part compiler is happy. What did I forget and how do I make it work?

Comment: What prevented you from indenting your code?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, since the preview did not show syntax highlighting I hoped that syntax and indentation will appear automagically once I post it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look into [dependent names](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#dependent).

To solve your issue, you need to use typename :

```
template <SomeEnum E>
SomeClass<E>::~SomeClass() {
   typename InnerMapType::iterator iter;
   //Iterate over resources
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.
Trivia question: Do you know why compiler says "missing semicolon" instead of giving a human-readable error message?

Comment: Depends on how good the compiler is. Comeau will say "error: nontype `InnerMapType::iterator` is not a type name"

Comment: the later compiler versions tend to be better with template errors. Yes, that error message is not very helpful, except for the line number

Comment: @Muxecoid: If you don't specify what exactly the nested name is (`typename` for types, `template` for templates), it will assume that it's a variable or function (and subsequently that `iter` is one too). However, since whitespace isn't overloadable, it will error like always when two names are directly beneath each other and the first one isn't a type. It expects you to write `InnerMapType::iterator; iter;`, however nonsensical that is to us. :)